# ColorBox Grouping Photos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

Im using color box, i have it working fine, except i don't understand how to add multiple images to the gallery when it is clicked.

But i need 2 images to appear for each flower.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a lot to explain here because you are using the example code, you need to add `rel="Example1"` attribute to your image tags. Each group of images must have a unique `rel` attribute value and a corresponding jQuery hook:

Your jQuery code:

```
$("a[rel='example1']").colorbox(); // Choose the type of colorbox instance you like and replicate it
$("a[rel='example2']").colorbox();
```

If all your images on the page have the same `rel` attribute value the colorbox instance will group all the images on your page into a slideshow.

```
<a href="images/floral/full-size/vegas-weddings-floral-1.jpg" rel="example1" title="Flower 1">
<a href="images/floral/full-size/vegas-weddings-floral-1.jpg" rel="example1" title="Flower 2">
<a href="images/floral/full-size/vegas-weddings-floral-1.jpg" rel="example1" title="Flower 3">

<a href="images/floral/full-size/vegas-weddings-floral-1.jpg" rel="example2" title="Flower 1">
<a href="images/floral/full-size/vegas-weddings-floral-1.jpg" rel="example2" title="Flower 2">
<a href="images/floral/full-size/vegas-weddings-floral-1.jpg" rel="example2" title="Flower 3">
```

Comment: Still figuring out how this post form works sorry if any code is missing.

Comment: @woodcreative There's a simple guide on the ask questions page, or if you're inclined, read the full guide here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. All editor toolbar items have tooltips, and the `?` button on the side will get you the full guide

Comment: You Rock my little Denim Pants! Thanks Both of You!

Comment: Thanks Jiang thats much better!

Answer (score 5):

Even better: automatic grouping of images by a rel or data-rel attribute.

```
<a href=".." class="colorbox" data-rel="group1"><..></a> 
<a href=".." class="colorbox" data-rel="group1"><..></a> 
<a href=".." class="colorbox" data-rel="group2"><..></a> 
<a href=".." class="colorbox" data-rel="group2"><..></a> 
<a href=".." class="colorbox" data-rel="group2"><..></a>
```

Configuration of colorbox - use a callback for rel property

```
$('.colorbox').colorbox({
    rel:function() {        
        return $(this).data('rel');
    }
});
```

(fixed a typo on jquery class selector)